# Unable to receive test emails from Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to send test email from Salesforce Marketing Cloud to Targeted recipients which are present in the DE. But its not delivered any of the subscribers. Even in My Tracking its showing zero sent,delivered. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Did the subscriber preview render correctly? Does the email contain any AMPscript? Try without the AMPscript part to check if there is something wrong. Additionally you can use the [Content Validation tools](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/validate/validate_an_email/) of SFMC

Comment: Yes Send Preview renders correctly. There is no Ampscript.  I have done Content Detective testing and Validation with corresponding Data Extension also No issue found.  All correct

Comment: Are they valid email addresses?

Comment: Raise a support ticket

Comment: Yes all are valid email addresses

Comment: Are the properties for the DE set to [Testable] & [Sendable]?

Comment: Are the subscribers in "All Subscribers" unsubscribed? Are you using Group email addresses, like "admin@" or other that may mean these email addresses fail List Detective validation?

Answer (score 1):

Are the records in the data extension tied to a subscriber key?
The actual contact lives at a higher level and the data extension is what it sounds like; an extension of existing data based on that subscriber.

You are not able to just create a data extension with [email], [first name], [last name] because SFMC doesn't treat the email attribute as a sendable profile.

Comment: Yes Subscriber key is tied with [Email] field